# regex match numbers in an array in a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have an array of values coming from bash which i just want to check if there are numbers or not in it. It can contain `-`, `+` numbers and spaces at the start or end since bash is evaluating this as sting.

Since every number is represented with `,` *at the end* i added `(,)` to the regex.

Basically i want to check if element is a number or not.

The `$val` look like these.

```
[ [ -0.13450142741203308, -0.3073260486125946, -0.15199440717697144, -0.06535257399082184, 0.02075939252972603, 0.03708624839782715, 0.04876817390322685 ] ,[ 0.10357733070850372, 0.048686813563108444, -0.1413831114768982, -0.11497996747493744, -0.08910851925611496, -0.04536910727620125, 0.06921301782131195, 0.02547631226480007 ] ]
```

This is my code which looks at each value and evaluates each. However it doesn't seem to catch the cases.

```sh
re='^[[:space:]][+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?(,)[[:space:]]$'

for j in ${val[*]}
do
  if ! [[ "$j" =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "Error: Not a number: $j"
  fi
done
```

Also it needs to ignore cases which throw `[` or `]` or `],`.

Any ideas how to correct this ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ya still doesnt catch.

Comment: How do you populate `$val`?

Comment: not every number ends with a comma.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes the last one does not end with a `,`

Comment: And this one neither: `0.04876817390322685 ] ,[`

Comment: Are the spaces guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that `$val` is coming to you as a string.

If you don't need to validate each number as a fully legit number, you can use shell logic to filter those things that are obviously not numbers:

```
val='[ [ -0.13450142741203308, -0.3073260486125946, -0.15199440717697144, -0.06535257399082184, 0.02075939252972603, 0.03708624839782715, 0.04876817390322685 ] ,[ 0.10357733070850372, 0.048686813563108444, -0.1413831114768982, -0.11497996747493744, -0.08910851925611496, -0.04536910727620125, 0.06921301782131195, 0.02547631226480007 ] ]'

for e in $val; do  # PURPOSELY no quote to break on spaces
    e="${e/,}"
    case $e in
        ''|*[!0-9.\-]*)  printf "'%s' is bad\n" "$e" ;;
        *) printf "'%s' is good\n" "$e" ;;
    esac
done
```

Prints:

```
'[' is bad
'[' is bad
'-0.13450142741203308' is good
'-0.3073260486125946' is good
'-0.15199440717697144' is good
'-0.06535257399082184' is good
'0.02075939252972603' is good
'0.03708624839782715' is good
'0.04876817390322685' is good
']' is bad
'[' is bad
'0.10357733070850372' is good
'0.048686813563108444' is good
'-0.1413831114768982' is good
'-0.11497996747493744' is good
'-0.08910851925611496' is good
'-0.04536910727620125' is good
'0.06921301782131195' is good
'0.02547631226480007' is good
']' is bad
']' is bad
```

That is super fast but that will fail on malformed 'numbers' such as `123-456`

---

If you *do* need to filter out malformed numbers, you can use `awk` for that:

```
echo "$val" | awk  -v RS="[^0-9.+-]+" '($0+0==$0)'
# all legit numbers from the string...
```

Comment: Thanks. I adjusted this to fit my script. `e="${e/,}"` removes the whitespaces ?

Comment: No. `e="${e/,}"` removes the trailing comma for those numbers that have it. It is a form of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) specifically `${parameter/pattern/string}` with `string` being nul for a deletion.

Comment: `${e%,}` requires a little less extrapolation to envision the predicted result, but they effectively do the same thing. `${e/,}` is like saying `${e/,/}`. The one difference is that `${e%,}` *only* works at the end. Assuming `e=123,456,` compare the outputs of `$: echo "${e/,} ${e/,/} ${e%,} ${e//,/}"`, which are
`123456, 123456, 123,456 123456`.

Answer (score 2):

If you populate `$val` with the given string, it's not an array, it's a string. Using it unquoted would apply *word splitting* to it which splits it into whitespace separated words. The spaces aren't part of the words, and some of the words (the last one in each bracketed sequence) don't end in a comma:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
val='[ [ -0.13450142741203308, -0.3073260486125946, -0.15199440717697144, -0.06535257399082184, 0.02075939252972603, 0.03708624839782715, 0.04876817390322685 ] ,[ 0.10357733070850372, 0.048686813563108444, -0.1413831114768982, -0.11497996747493744, -0.08910851925611496, -0.04536910727620125, 0.06921301782131195, 0.02547631226480007 ] ]'

re='^[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?,?$'

for j in $val ; do
    if ! [[ $j =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo "Error: Not a number: $j"
    fi
done
```

To use a bash array, declare it with round parentheses and use whitespace to separate the elements:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
val=(-0.13450142741203308 -0.3073260486125946 -0.15199440717697144 -0.06535257399082184 0.02075939252972603 0.03708624839782715 0.04876817390322685 0.10357733070850372 0.048686813563108444 -0.1413831114768982 -0.11497996747493744 -0.08910851925611496 -0.04536910727620125 0.06921301782131195 0.02547631226480007)

re='^[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'

for j in "${val[@]}" ; do
    if ! [[ $j =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo "Error: Not a number: $j"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. But the output comes in as `[ 0.13, -.145, ]` and so on in `val` and not  as `()`.

Comment: Then it's not an array in bash, even if it might be one in Python or whatever else language.

Comment: Ya. May be it is evaluating it as a string. But the point is i cant change `$val` . Also they are `,` separated except the last.

Comment: Are they? `0.04876817390322685 ] ,[`. The first snippet works with a string.